# React exclude one object from array while mapping through the component

Tags: reactjs

```
    selected_fields = [{
      "name":"date"
    },{
      "name":"cpc"
    },{
      "name":"ctc"
    },{
      "name":"cpc"
    },{
      "name":"spend"
    }]



    {
      selected_fields.map(( selected_field, index ) => (
        <div className="col-2">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-center">{selected_field.name}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))
    }
```

Here i am trying to remove "date" field from the array while mapping .

The reason i want while mapping because i  am using  same data some where else

Is there any way to do that ? PLease have a look

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.fliter` out the items before applying `.map`

```
selected_fields
   .filter(selected_field => selected_field.name !== 'date')
   .map(( selected_field, index ) // your other code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific requirement you can use reduce, it filter and return new array like map in single iteration, use the below code -

```
render() {

var selected_fields = [
  {
    name: "date"
  },
  {
    name: "cpc"
  },
  {
    name: "ctc"
  },
  {
    name: "cpc"
  },
  {
    name: "spend"
  }
];

return (
  <>
    {selected_fields.reduce(function(filtered, selected_field) {
      if (selected_field.name !== "date") {
        var filteredItem = (
          <div className="col-2">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-center">
                  {selected_field.name}
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
        filtered.push(filteredItem);
      }
      return filtered;
    }, [])}
  </>
);
```

}